# Sorting and filtering data dynamically

Tags: beginner, sorting, rust

This application collects data from an external database (neo4j) on start-up and then provides one HTTP end-point where one can get a filtered and sorted response based on some JSON that's passed along in the body of the request.

**main.rs:**

```
#![feature(plugin)]
#![plugin(rocket_codegen)]

extern crate rusted_cypher;
extern crate rocket;
#[macro_use]
extern crate rocket_contrib;
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;
extern crate serde_json;
extern crate serde;
extern crate time;

use std::collections::HashMap;

use rusted_cypher::GraphClient;
use rocket_contrib::{JSON, Value};
use rocket::State;

fn get_year_of_release_date(release_date: i64) -> u16 {
    time::at_utc(time::Timespec {
                     nsec: 0,
                     sec: release_date,
                 })
            .tm_year as u16 + 1900
}

fn load_data() -> Vec<Media> {
    // TODO: get neo4j server url from environment
    let graph = GraphClient::connect("http://serveraddress:7474/db/data").unwrap();
    // query is a simple match of nodes that returns an id, rating, release date for collected nodes and sorts them by rating in descending order
    let results = graph.exec(query).unwrap();
    let mut data: Vec<Media> = Vec::new();
    for row in results.rows() {
        data.push(Media {
                      id: row.get("id").unwrap(),
                      rating: row.get("rating").unwrap(),
                      year: get_year_of_release_date(row.get("releaseDate").unwrap_or(0)),
                  });
    }

    data
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Media {
    id: String,
    rating: u16,
    year: u16,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, Clone)]
struct RecsysObject {
    #[serde(rename = "pageSize")]
    page_size: Option<usize>,
    page: Option<usize>,
    filters: Option<HashMap<String, SimpleYearFilter>>,
    sort: Option<Vec<HashMap<String, String>>>,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, Clone)]
struct SimpleYearFilter {
    #[serde(rename = "$eq")]
    eq: Option<u16>,
    #[serde(rename = "$and")]
    and: Option<Vec<LogicFilter>>,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, Clone)]
enum LogicFilter {
    #[serde(rename = "$gt")]
    GT(u16),
    #[serde(rename = "$lt")]
    LT(u16),
}

impl RecsysObject {
    fn construct_filter(self: &Self, movie: &Media) -> bool {
        match self.filters.clone() {
            None => true,
            Some(f) => {
                match f.get("year") {
                    None => true,
                    Some(yf) => {
                        match yf.eq {
                            Some(year) => movie.year == year,
                            None => {
                                match yf.and.clone() {
                                    None => true,
                                    Some(rangefilter) => {
                                        for rf in rangefilter {
                                            match rf {
                                                LogicFilter::LT(val) => {
                                                    if movie.year >= val {
                                                        return false;
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                LogicFilter::GT(val) => {
                                                    if movie.year <= val {
                                                        return false;
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                        true
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#[post("/", data = "<object>")]
fn one_point_of_success(allmovies: State<Vec<Media>>, object: JSON<RecsysObject>) -> JSON<Value> {
    let mut results = allmovies
                    .iter()
                    .filter(|m| object.construct_filter(m))
                    .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    match object.sort.clone() {
        None => (),
        Some(v) => {
            match v.get(0) {
                None => (),
                Some(hmap) => {
                    match hmap.get("property") {
                        None => {
                            if hmap.get("type").unwrap() == "popularity" {
                                match hmap.get("order") {
                                    Some(order) => {
                                        if order == "ascending" {
                                            results.sort_by(|a, b| a.rating.cmp(&b.rating));
                                        }
                                    }
                                    _ => {
                                        () // already sorted
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        _ => {
                            if hmap.get("property").unwrap() == "metadata.releaseDate" {
                                match hmap.get("order") {
                                    Some(order) => {
                                        if order == "ascending" {
                                            results.sort_by(|a, b| a.year.cmp(&b.year));
                                        } else {
                                            results.sort_by(|a, b| b.year.cmp(&a.year));
                                        }
                                    }
                                    _ => {
                                        results.sort_by(|a, b| b.year.cmp(&a.year));
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                ()
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
    JSON(json!(results.iter().skip(object.page.unwrap_or(0) * object.page_size.unwrap_or(10)) // first page is page 0
                    .take(object.page_size.unwrap_or(10)).collect::<Vec<_>>()))

}

fn main() {
    rocket::ignite()
        .manage(load_data())
        .mount("/", routes![one_point_of_success])
        .launch();
}
```

These types of filters/sorts are available to be sent as a JSON body into the POST request:

**Single year filter**

```json
{"filters":{"year":{"$eq":1984}},"pageSize":10,"page":0}
```

**Year range filter**

```json
{"filters":{"year":{"$and":[{"$gt":1982},{"$lt":1989}]}},"pageSize":10,"page":0}
```

**Year range filter + year sort**

```json
{"filters":{"year":{"$and":[{"$gt":1900},{"$lt":2007}]}},"sort":[{"type":"property","property":"metadata.releaseDate","order":"descending"}],"pageSize":100,"page":310}
```

**Year range filter + popularity sort**

```json
{"filters":{"year":{"$and":[{"$gt":1900},{"$lt":2018}]}},"sort":[{"type":"popularity","order":"descending"}],"pageSize":10,"page":0}
```

**Popularity sort**

```json
{"sort":[{"type":"popularity","order":"descending"}],"pageSize":10,"page":0}
```

**Year sort**

```json
{"sort":[{"type":"property","property":"metadata.releaseDate","order":"ascending"}],"pageSize":10,"page":0}
```

While putting everything into a vector might not be the best choice in terms of filtering and sorting, the performance is good enough. I'm primarily concerned on how ugly I've implemented the filtering and sorting, so I'm looking for feedback to improve on that, preferably with some concrete examples.

For completeness, this is built on nightly Rust with these dependencies:

```json
rusted_cypher = "1.1.0"
rocket = { git = "https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket" }
rocket_codegen = { git = "https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket" }
rocket_contrib = { git = "https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket" }
serde = "1.0.2"
serde_json = "1.0.1"
serde_derive = "1.0.2"
time = "0.1"
```

Comment: Your code cannot be compiled: *cannot find value `query` in this scope* in `load_data()`

Comment: query is a simple match of nodes that returns an id, rating, release date for collected nodes and sorts them by rating in descending order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `time` crate, I recommend you use the [`chrono`](https://crates.io/crates/chrono) crate. It's not as low-level as `time` and it has more features. For example, with `chrono`, we don't need to add a magic `1900` value in `get_year_of_release_date`.

```
extern crate chrono;

use chrono::{Datelike, NaiveDateTime};

// Datelike::year() returns i32, not u16,
// so I propagated that change throughout the program.
fn get_year_of_release_date(release_date: i64) -> i32 {
    NaiveDateTime::from_timestamp(release_date, 0).year()
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, Clone)]
struct SimpleYearFilter {
    #[serde(rename = "$eq")]
    eq: Option<i32>,
    #[serde(rename = "$and")]
    and: Option<Vec<LogicFilter>>,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, Clone)]
enum LogicFilter {
    #[serde(rename = "$gt")]
    GT(i32),
    #[serde(rename = "$lt")]
    LT(i32),
}
```

Next, you've got some deeply nested sets of matches. You're also performing some unnecessary clones in those matches. Let's address this first. When you match on a lvalue that you can't move, you can obtain a *reference* to an interior value by adding `ref` before the binding. This means that the bound variable will not contain the value directly, only a reference to the value. For example:

```
impl RecsysObject {
    fn construct_filter(self: &Self, movie: &Media) -> bool {
        match self.filters {
            None => true,
            Some(ref f) => {
                match f.get("year") {
                    None => true,
                    Some(yf) => {
                        match yf.eq {
                            Some(year) => movie.year == year,
                            None => {
                                match yf.and {
                                    None => true,
                                    Some(ref rangefilter) => {
                                        for rf in rangefilter {
                                            match *rf {
                                                LogicFilter::LT(val) => {
                                                    if movie.year >= val {
                                                        return false;
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                LogicFilter::GT(val) => {
                                                    if movie.year <= val {
                                                        return false;
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                        true
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On the first match, when `self.filters` is a `Some`, `f` will contain a reference to the `HashMap`.

When we get to the `for rf in rangefilter` loop, `rangefilter` is now a reference too. Generally, when we iterate on a reference to a collection, the iterator emits references too. Indeed, `rf` is now a reference to a `LogicFilter`. Here, I wrote `match *rf` to match the dereferenced value (note that this doesn't necessarily copy or clone the whole `LogicFilter`) because we bind `i32` values, which are cheap to copy, so we bind them by value, not by reference.

Finally, let's simplify these nested matches. Let's look at `RecsysObject::construct_filter` first:

```
impl RecsysObject {
    fn construct_filter(&self, movie: &Media) -> bool {
        self.filters.as_ref().map_or(true, |f| {
            f.get("year").map_or(true, |yf| {
                if let Some(year) = yf.eq {
                    movie.year == year
                } else {
                    yf.and.as_ref().map_or(true,
                        |range_filter| range_filter.iter().all(|rf| rf.matches(movie.year)))
                }
            })
        })
    }
}

impl LogicFilter {
    fn matches(&self, actual: i32) -> bool {
        match *self {
            LogicFilter::LT(expected) => actual < expected,
            LogicFilter::GT(expected) => actual > expected,
        }
    }
}
```

Here, we're merely computing a value, so functional style is appropriate here. I'm using [`map_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map_or) (`map_or(d, f)` is a shorthand for `map(f).unwrap_or(d)`) to simplify the matches where `None` returns `true`. I need to use [`as_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref) a couple times to turn a `&Option<T>` into an `Option<&T>`, because `map_or` takes `self` by value but we don't own either `Option<T>` in that function.

I've replaced the `for` loop with [`all`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.all), which takes care of exiting early when a `false` value is encountered. ([`any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.any) does the opposite.)

We could also use `and_then` to remove one level of nesting.

```
impl RecsysObject {
    fn construct_filter(&self, movie: &Media) -> bool {
        self.filters.as_ref()
            .and_then(|f| f.get("year"))
            .map_or(true, |yf| {
                if let Some(year) = yf.eq {
                    movie.year == year
                } else {
                    yf.and.as_ref().map_or(true,
                        |range_filter| range_filter.iter().all(|rf| rf.matches(movie.year)))
                }
            })
    }
}
```

Now for `one_point_of_success`:

```
#[post("/", data = "<object>")]
fn one_point_of_success(all_movies: State<Vec<Media>>, object: JSON<RecsysObject>) -> JSON<Value> {
    let mut results = all_movies
        .iter()
        .filter(|m| object.construct_filter(m))
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    if let Some(ref v) = object.sort {
        if let Some(hmap) = v.get(0) {
            match hmap.get("property").map(AsRef::as_ref) {
                Some("metadata.releaseDate") => {
                    if hmap.get("order").map_or("ascending", AsRef::as_ref) == "ascending" {
                        results.sort_by_key(|result| result.year);
                    } else {
                        results.sort_by_key(|result| RevOrd(result.year));
                    }
                }
                None => {
                    if hmap.get("type").expect("Expected either a `property` or a `type` attribute") == "popularity" {
                        if let Some("ascending") = hmap.get("order").map(AsRef::as_ref) {
                            results.sort_by_key(|result| result.rating);
                        } else {
                            // already sorted
                        }
                    }
                }
                _ => {}
            }
        }
    }

    JSON(json!(results.iter().skip(object.page.unwrap_or(0) * object.page_size.unwrap_or(10)) // first page is page 0
                      .take(object.page_size.unwrap_or(10)).collect::<Vec<_>>()))
}
```

The sorting part doesn't produce a value, it merely mutates an existing value (the `results` vector), so imperative style fits best. I'm using `if let` to simplify the matches where we only do something on one branch.

Other details:

- Write `&self` instead of `self: &Self`.
- Use [`sort_by_key`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.sort_by_key) instead of `sort_by` when you apply the same transformation on both values. To sort in descending (reverse) order, wrap the value in a [`RevOrd`](https://docs.rs/revord/0.0.2/revord/struct.RevOrd.html) from the [`revord`](https://crates.io/crates/revord) crate. If you ever need to sort on multiple values (sort by X then by Y...), just wrap them in a tuple (tuples implement `Ord` for up to 12 elements; if you need more, you can nest tuples as a workaround).
- You can `match` on string slices on string literals. If you have an `Option<&String>`, you need to convert it to an `Option<&str>`, which is what I'm doing with `.map(AsRef::as_ref)`.
- Use `expect` instead of `unwrap` in order to provide an error message that gives some context when an unexpected condition does occur.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `map` and `collect` instead of iterating over something and pushing to a `Vec`. This avoids the need for a mutable variable and provides more efficient memory allocation.
2. Use `expect` instead of `unwrap`. `expect` has some useful error text presented to the end user when it fails.
3. `Option<HashMap>` is a little surprising. You may be able to just get away with a `HashMap` because it can hold zero values.
4. Idiomatic Rust naming is not to have consecutive uppercase letters in `CamelCase` names. That means it should be `Lt`; not `LT`.
5. Don't use `self: &Self`; that's idiomatically `&self`.
6. `construct_filter` seems like a poor name; it doesn't *construct* anything. It applies the filters, so perhaps that might be better.
7. There's no reason to clone the filters. Instead match on references (e.g. `Some(ref foo)`) or use methods like `Option:as_ref`.
8. Instead of iterating over things yourself, use iterator adapters like `Iterator::any` and `Iterator::all`.
9. The use of negative logic ("does this filter *not* match this element") is really confusing. Flip it around.
10. Extract methods to the structs and enums where they are most relevant. This also allows you to decrease nesting.
11. The query structure doesn't make sense; you can have both equality and less-than filters concurrently, but you only apply equality when both exist. Perhaps different datatypes might express your domain restrictions better.
12. You can flatten the `equal` / `and` match into one level by matching against a tuple.
13. Review all of [`Option`'s methods](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html); you are going to be using them **a lot**. For example, `map`, `as_ref`, `and_then` are super common.
14. Don't unwrap `property` - just match on the `Some()` instead of `_`.
15. A missing `else` is already a `()`, no need to explicitly write it out.
16. Flatten out the sorting match too. Doing so shows it's *really strange* to apply the sort on three keys, instead of just two ("column" and "direction")...
17. Consider validating the sort parameters and converting them into two enums (column, direction). This splits up the concerns about which strings are valid, which are used for sorting, and would allow you to simply the sorting match.
18. Use `if let` when you only care about one variant of an enum.
19. Temporary variables like `page` and `page_size` are your friend. Avoids repeating the default of `10`, for example.
20. Seems like it'd more efficient to take a slice of `results` instead of collecting into a vec.

```
#![feature(plugin)]
#![plugin(rocket_codegen)]

extern crate rusted_cypher;
extern crate rocket;
#[macro_use]
extern crate rocket_contrib;
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;
extern crate serde_json;
extern crate serde;
extern crate time;

use std::collections::HashMap;

use rusted_cypher::GraphClient;
use rocket_contrib::{JSON, Value};
use rocket::State;

fn get_year_of_release_date(release_date: i64) -> u16 {
    time::at_utc(time::Timespec {
                     nsec: 0,
                     sec: release_date,
                 })
            .tm_year as u16 + 1900
}

fn load_data() -> Vec<Media> {
    // TODO: get neo4j server url from environment
    let graph = GraphClient::connect("http://serveraddress:7474/db/data").unwrap();
    // query is a simple match of nodes that returns an id, rating, release date for collected nodes and sorts them by rating in descending order
    let query = "I didn't provide a value so this is just something";
    let results = graph.exec(query).unwrap();

    results.rows().map(|row| {
        Media {
            id: row.get("id").unwrap(),
            rating: row.get("rating").unwrap(),
            year: get_year_of_release_date(row.get("releaseDate").unwrap_or(0)),
        }
    }).collect();
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Media {
    id: String,
    rating: u16,
    year: u16,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, Clone)]
struct RecsysObject {
    #[serde(rename = "pageSize")]
    page_size: Option<usize>,
    page: Option<usize>,
    filters: Option<HashMap<String, SimpleYearFilter>>,
    sort: Option<Vec<HashMap<String, String>>>,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, Clone)]
struct SimpleYearFilter {
    #[serde(rename = "$eq")]
    eq: Option<u16>,
    #[serde(rename = "$and")]
    and: Option<Vec<LogicFilter>>,
}

impl SimpleYearFilter {
    fn passes(&self, value: u16) -> bool {
        match (self.eq, &self.and) {
            (Some(my_val), _) => {
                value == my_val
            }
            (None, &Some(ref range_filters)) => {
                range_filters.iter().all(|filter| filter.passes(value))
            }
            _ => true,
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, Clone)]
enum LogicFilter {
    #[serde(rename = "$gt")]
    Gt(u16),
    #[serde(rename = "$lt")]
    Lt(u16),
}

impl LogicFilter {
    fn passes(&self, value: u16) -> bool {
        match *self {
            LogicFilter::Lt(my_val) => value < my_val,
            LogicFilter::Gt(my_val) => value > my_val,
        }
    }
}

impl RecsysObject {
    fn construct_filter(&self, movie: &Media) -> bool {
        self.filters.as_ref().and_then(|f| {
            f.get("year").map(|yf| yf.passes(movie.year))
        }).unwrap_or(true)
    }
}

#[post("/", data = "<object>")]
fn one_point_of_success(allmovies: State<Vec<Media>>, object: JSON<RecsysObject>) -> JSON<Value> {
    let mut results = allmovies
                    .iter()
                    .filter(|m| object.construct_filter(m))
                    .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    if let Some(hmap) = object.sort.as_ref().and_then(|v| v.get(0)) {
        let property = hmap.get("property").map(String::as_str);
        let typ = hmap.get("type").map(String::as_str);
        let order = hmap.get("order").map(String::as_str);

        match (property, typ, order) {
            (None, Some("popularity"), Some("ascending")) =>
                results.sort_by(|a, b| a.rating.cmp(&b.rating)),
            (Some("metadata.releaseDate"), _, Some("ascending")) =>
                results.sort_by(|a, b| a.year.cmp(&b.year)),
            (Some("metadata.releaseDate"), _, _) =>
                results.sort_by(|a, b| b.year.cmp(&a.year)),
            _ => {
                // Do nothing - unknown sort or default sort
            }
        }
    };

    let page = object.page.unwrap_or(0);
    let page_size = object.page_size.unwrap_or(10);

    let foo = results.iter().skip(page * page_size) // first page is page 0
        .take(page_size).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    JSON(json!(foo))
}

fn main() {
    rocket::ignite()
        .manage(load_data())
        .mount("/", routes![one_point_of_success])
        .launch();
}
```